# Can americans break american laws while in another country?

Tags: united-states, international

If a 20 year old american brings his 16 year old america girlfriend to a country where the legal age of consent is 14, and then have sex with her there, is he liable to be prosecuted back in the US?

Comment: Is that example set in stone, or would it be okay for your theoretical curiosity, if those two *met* in that foreign country each for their own reasons? Because "bringing" her is it's own can of worms and certainly started on US soil.

Comment: So if it does make a difference, then please explain what happens in both scenarios.

Comment: Also please note while for example, the age of consent in my country *is* 14, that only goes for other 14-16 year olds. A 20 year old who has power over the minor (for example by holding the return tickets) having sex with her still is illegal. So you may want to shrink your example a lot if you really want to know about an action that is legal in another country.

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering your title question and assuming that you meant to present a circumstance that would actually trigger criminal liability, but based on the ages you've actually used in your hypothetical, you may not have done so. I'll ignore that complication and just present what the law is. **Yes, there are some U.S. laws that people can be found to violate while in another country.**

The Department of Justice has [a "citizen's guide"](https://www.justice.gov/criminal-ceos/citizens-guide-us-federal-law-extraterritorial-sexual-exploitation-children) explaining extraterritorial sexual exploitation of children. The main offences are:

- [18 U.S.C. § 2423(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2423): Transportation with intent to engage in criminal sexual activity
- [18 U.S.C. § 2423(d)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2423): Travel with intent to engage in illicit sexual conduct
- [18 U.S.C. § 2423(c)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2423): Engaging in illicit sexual conduct in foreign places

For § 2423(a), there must be the intent to engage in "any sexual activity for which any person can be charged with a criminal offense."

For § 2423(b) and (c), "illicit sexual conduct" means, among a few other things: "a sexual act (as defined in section 2246) with a person under 18 years of age that would be in violation of [chapter 109A](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/part-I/chapter-109A) if the sexual act occurred in the special maritime and territorial jurisdiction of the United States."

Chapter 109A includes § 2243(a):

> Whoever, in the special maritime and territorial jurisdiction of the United States or in a Federal prison, or in any prison, institution, or facility in which persons are held in custody by direction of or pursuant to a contract or agreement with the head of any Federal department or agency, knowingly engages in a sexual act with another person who
>
> (a) has attained the age of 12 years but has not attained the age of 16 years; and
>
> (b) is at least four years younger than the person so engaging;
>
> or attempts to do so, shall be fined under this title, imprisoned not more than 15 years, or both.